# Blague québécoise sur « Is he gone? »

Tags: humour, canada

J'ai noté notre test provincial des compétences linguistiques en Ontario la semaine passée. La chef de notre salle était franco-ontarienne, et elle nous a raconté une blague que je n'ai pas pu saisir.

En voici la transcription :

> Le téléphone sonne chez une Québécoise. C’est un anglophone qui appelle. Il demande : « Is your husband there? » Elle répond : « Non. » Il demande encore : « Is he gone? /ɪzigɔn/ » Elle répond : « Is he gone pas ! /izigɔnpɑ/ Il est parti ! »

Il est clair que la blague se base sur la prononciation, donc voici **[un enregistrement](https://unfamiliarplace.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/blague-1.mp3)** si ça aide.

Si quelqu'un peut l'éclairer, j'en serai reconnaissant. :)

Comment: Update: Tried this out on a 10yo whose mom is Québécoise. He instantly cracked up and then identified the two phrases being played on. The answer below is thus confirmed in the field. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> — **Is he gone?**         /ɪzigɔn/ (pris pour "*y'zigonne ?*", c-à-d "***il [zigonne](http://www.dictionnaire-quebecois.com/definitions-z.html) ?***")
>   — ***Il zigonne pas !***   /izigɔnpɑ/

Zigonner est inconnu en France, mais la prononciation simplifiée des pronoms personnels y est courante : ***i*** pour ***il***, ***a*** ou ***è*** pour **elle**, ***ch'*** pour ***je***, ***t'*** pour ***tu*** et ***i*** ou ***z*** pour ***ils***.

Source: www.dictionnaire-quebecois.com

> Zigonner : Verbe propre au langage populaire québécois, on l’utilise dans les cas suivants : [1] pour signifier le fait de travailler inefficacement ; [2] pour indiquer le fait de peiner à l’accomplissement de quelque chose (ex : j’ai beau zigonner après cette foutue machine mais j’arrive pas à la réparer) ; [3] pour marquer l’acte d’un chien qui s'accroche à quelqu'un ou quelque chose pour simuler une copulation.

Voir aussi [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/zigonner) et https://oreilletendue.com/2014/01/08/detresse-du-jour/ où l'on trouve une étymologie possible :

> La suite logicielle Antidote propose l’étymologie suivante :
>
> Emprunt au poitevin ou saintongeais zigzounàe, «scier maladroitement»; de l’onomatopée zik-zak, «bruit du va-et-vient d’une scie».

Answer (score 8):

En complément, voir aussi le [*Glossaire du parler français du Canada*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwihjIvN3sbhAhUHuVkKHeWMB8cQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbibnum2.banq.qc.ca%2Fbna%2Fnumtxt%2F179630.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0a9B_qKhStTeebWgGecrVv) (1930, Société du parler français au Canada) :

[image]

On écrit le mot au Québec depuis 1903 (employé plus anciennement à l'oral) et on y voit la même origine onomatopéique que [*zigouiller*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/zigouiller) ; il s'est déjà employé pour [*tisonner*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tisonner) (*digonner*, Normandie) et « mal jouer du violon ». (DHLF)

Aujourd'hui *zigonner* c'est soit *perdre son temps* ou *travailler à des choses sans importance* (voir [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/zigonner) ; peut-être aussi concrètement avec une *serrure* pour « chercher à pénétrer », DHLF) mais c'est vraiment la prononciation du [*i(l)*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Troisi%C3%A8me_personne_du_singulier_%C2%AB_il_%C2%BB) devant le verbe conjugué (*il zigonne*) qui fait en sorte que c'est essentiellement identique à la prononciation de « is he gone ? » en anglais que l'interlocuteur interprète comme un propos en français d'où sa réponse « i(l) zigonne pas, il est parti » et la blague.

Comment: Est-ce que "Il est parti" peut s'abrèger/se prononcer comme/en "i(l)/y est (y'est?) parti", et si c'est le cas, est-ce possible que la blaque emploie/exige la version complète ("Il est parti") pour ne pas "dévoiler"/faire allusion à l'astuce derrière la blague? Thanks!

Comment: @PapaPoule Oui, c'est [noté/prononcé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#%C3%8Atre) « y'é (parti) » (dans l'enregistrement on dit bien _il est parti_). Bien dans le sens où si quelqu'un n'a jamais entendu et ne reconnaît pas le verbe _zigonner_, il peut comprendre uniquement « _is he gone_ pas » au lieu de « i(l) zigonne pas » et la blague reste incomprise. Mais selon moi ça dépend surtout de s'il a reconnu justement ce verbe-là et sa forme conjuguée. Je ne pense pas que le pronom _il_ vende la mèche... ou je ne vois pas exactement ce que ça changerait...

Comment: @PapaPoule Comme par exemple enfant on me raconte la blague suivante « Qu'est-ce qu'une vache prend dans un bar ? »... « un p'tit coup »... ?? La personne parlait allemand, c'est « die kuh » (la vache)... je ne l'ai jamais comprise hahaha.